# How to convert character '1' and character '0' to an integer 10 in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer

i have a problem, i'm trying to read a image file, in this file have the number of column and line and i'm trying to read only this information to create a matrix of pixeis.
ex: `char numb[2];
numb[0]='1';
numb[1]='0';`
i'm trying to transform to int numb=10;
thanks

Comment: Hint: '1' - '0' = 1, '0' - '0' = 0, 10 = 1 * 10 + 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this as a start:

```
if (isdigit(numb[0]) && isdigit(numb[1])) {
    int val = (numb[0] - '0') * 10 + (numb[1] - '0');
}
```

An alternative way would be:

```
char str[3] = { numb[0], numb[1], '\0' };
char* enptr;
int val = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

if (*endptr != '\0')
    /* failed to convert */
```

But it hardly has much benefit over the former approach (in this particular case)

Comment: ANSI C **does** guarantee that the character encoding of the decimal digits are ordered and contiguous.

Comment: C11 **§5.2.1 Character sets, ¶3**: "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous."

Comment: Could you please point me to the specific paragraph in the Standard? AFAIR, there aren't _any_ assumptions on the nature and structure of the character set.

Comment: There are several assumptions; that all of the English alphabet and several punctuation marks exist, for example.  Besides that, there is an additional restriction on the ordering of the digits, as mentioned above.

Comment: That's what I meant. Somehow I recalled that same lack of requirement was applied to digits as well. Looks like I was wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you could write your answer to use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` since you recommend against using `atoi()`?

Answer (score 3):

If it's always 2-digit:

```
int n = (numb[0] - '0')*10 + (numb[1] - '0');
```

Or you can declare `char numb[3]`, so that `numb[0]='1', numb[1]='0', numb[2]='\0'` (basically, converting it to a null-terminated string) and use `strtol`:

```
int n = strtol(numb, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Better to recommend `strtol` than `atoi`.